# What is Virtual-Key Code for '='?

Tags: delphi

I've checked on microsoft's [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx), but I couldn't find it.

[image: Keyboard image]

Comment: My delphi 7 does not recognize any VK_OEM_xxxx values. It says 
[Error] Unit1.pas(29): Undeclared identifier: 'VK_OEM_PLUS'

Comment: Windows SDK doesn't have any code for it.

Comment: @Atak_Snajpera: None of the `VK_OEM_xxx` values are defined in Delphi 7 (except for `VK_OEM_CLEAR`), but are defined in later versions (at least D2006) in Delphi's `Windows` unit.

Comment: `=` is not its own key on standard keyboards, that is why there is no virtual key code for it.  It is shared with the `+` key, which is `VK_OEM_PLUS`. Both characters use the same key code, and the current shift state decides which character gets produced.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the virtual key code for <kbd>=</kbd> is 187 (described in MSDN documentation as `VK_OEM_PLUS`):

```
keybd_event(VK_OEM_PLUS, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: You aren't meant to call keybd_event the days, as described in the docs

Comment: Use `SendInput()` instead.  And if you use its `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` flag, you can send the actual `'='` character as text and not worry about using a virtual key code at all.

Answer (score 0):

Windows SDK does not define any common code for equal sign. In Windows SDK 10.0.15063.0 is only **VK_OEM_NEC_EQUAL** for NEC PC-9800 keyboard.

Comment: That is because some NEC PC-9800 keyboards have a dedicated `=` key on them.  Most keyboards don't.

Comment: Downvoter might have found a virtual key code for equal sign char defined in Windows SDK. Could they share it with us? Maybe it's some Windows SDK Special Edition.